# The existence of a choice function when every $X\in S$ is a singleton $X =\{x\}$

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I'm reading **Set Theory by Thomas Jech** but can't figure out the reason of the statement below:

---

In some trivial cases, the existence of a choice function can be proved outright in ZF:

when every $X\in S$ is a singleton $X=\{x\}$.

But one cannot prove existence of a choice function (in ZF) just:

when every $X\in S$ is a set of two elements.

---

I can't figure out why. I'll appreciate it if you could **prove the first statement** and **provide a counterexample of the second statement** to let me understand them.

Comment: I think you can use the [axiom of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement).  It follows from the axiom that if you can define a function $\phi_f$ on $S$ in the sense that for any $X$ in $S$ there is a unique $Y$ with $\phi_f[X,Y]$ then there exists an actual function $f$ with $\phi_f[X,f(X)]$.  And clearly $\{x\}\mapsto x$ is defineable in the above sense.

Comment: It's similar when you look at non-empty subsets of natural numbers only, you can always return the smallest number of each set.  (Or non-empty subsets of some other well-ordered set.)

Comment: We can't quite "provide a counterexample", since that involves constructing models of ZF, which is not a trivial thing if you don't have the sufficient technical background. Keep reading the book, in Chapter 15 he gets there.

Comment: @fweth Thank you. But why can't I find a function $\{x,y\}$ to $x$ similarly? Where is the difference between one element and two elements?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Huesic you can't say $\{x,y\}\mapsto x$ because it's not an ordered pair.  So you'd need some kind of deterministic algorithm which always selects the same element.  For example, when $x$ and $y$ are subsets of real numbers, I cannot think of a universal way to select one over the other.

Comment: @fweth Thank you. Your answer is really helpful for me.

Comment: @fweth But can I say that if $A$ is a set, then $x\in A$ is a set, and then $\langle A, x\rangle$ is a set, then use axiom of replacement to replace every $A$ by $\langle A, x\rangle$ respectively, so I get the function $\{\langle A, x\rangle\}$ actually exists as a set? Where is the problem?

Comment: For the axiom of replacement you need uniqueness.  If $x\in A$ and $y\in A$ and they are not equal, then how do you compose a formula $\phi$ such that $\phi[A,x]$ holds but not $\phi[A,y]$?

Comment: @fweth So, I think I have missed that a formula needs to be constructed by some rules. I wrongly thought I could assign any $(A,x)$ to $0$ or $1$(intuitively) but actually it is not always possible to construct such a formula. Thank you for correcting my wrong opinion.

Comment: Basically all axioms tell you that some set exists of which you already know exactly how it looks like.  That's not completely true, as the axioms are more vague in order to make them easier to verify, e.g. for every $x,y$ there exists $z$ such that $x\in z$ and $y\in z$ but the idea is that $z$ is already the set $\{x,y\}$.  The axiom of choice is the only exception, because you can invoke it even when you can't describe the set you are excepting uniquely.

Comment: @fweth Thank you for your helpful words.

Comment: The function you want is simply $F\colon a \mapsto \bigcup a$, because for singletons, $\bigcup \{x\} = x$. Now apply Replacement — no need for AC in this case. $F$ restricted to $X$ is a choice function for $X$.

Comment: @BrianO Thank you for your answer. What confused me was why a set of one element can be do so while two elements cannot. What I missed was that I wrongly thought I could assign any $(A,x)$ to $0$ or $1$ by a formula (used in axiom of replacement) but actually it is not always possible to construct such a formula.